# Django generic.ListView: do not display Questions that have no specified Choices

Tags: django, django-models

The models are:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Some Questions have no Choices specified by the admin. I don't want to display such Questions.

If the solution is to override get_queryset, then how to do that? Or is it better to get all Questions (`Question.objects.all()`) and to filter them in the view?

```
class QuestionList(generic.ListView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        # How?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either set the `queryset` attribute on the View

```
class QuestionList(generic.ListView):
    model = Question
    queryset = Question.objects.filter(choice__isnull=False).distinct()
```

Or override `get_queryset`

```
class QuestionList(generic.ListView):
    model = Question

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(choice__isnull=False).distinct()
```

Comment: The view loops through the queryset and displays each item like this: `<li><a href={% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}>{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>`
The problem with the both suggestions is that the question is displayed not once, but as many times as the question has choices. For example, if question has 'Yes' and 'No' choices, it will be displayed two times.

Comment: Just need to add `.distinct()` to not get duplicates